# group of checkboxes with that work correctly

Tags: html, angular, checkbox

I searched a lot but couldn't find a correct answer that I'm looking for.
I want to have a group of checkboxes in a form that if they are checked, they work correct and show it in a div tag.

```
export class MyComponent {
options = [
{name:'OptionA', value:'1', checked:true},
{name:'OptionB', value:'2', checked:false},
{name:'OptionC', value:'3', checked:true}
]
get selectedOptions() { // right now: ['1','3']
return this.options
          .filter(opt => opt.checked)
          .map(opt => opt.value)
  }
}
```

and html:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="options">Options:</label>
<div *ngFor="let option of options">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
               name="options"
               value="{{option.value}}"
               [(ngModel)]="option.checked"/>
        {{option.name}}
    </label>
</div>
```

but I'm sure it's not correct because the checked property is given by myself and if user changes it doesn't work.
Could you please help me to write a simple code for checkbox?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `[checked]` attribute, also remove the `ngModel` and just bind value to `(change)` event:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox"
           name="options"
           value="{{option.value}}"
           [checked]="option.checked" 
           (change)="option.checked = !option.checked"/>
    {{option.name}}
</label>
```